# Python ascii error after for loop

Tags: python

When I run this simple program in python I get an ascii error after "for line in file". I have tried many changes with no success. Why am I running into this issue?

Code:

```
flashcards = {}

def Gaelic():
    file = open ("gaelic_flashcard_mode.txt", "r")
    for line in file:
        print("clear4")
        line1 = line.rstrip().split("=")
        key = line1[0]
        trans = line1[1]
        PoS = line1[2]
        flashcards[key] = [trans, PoS]
    print(flashcards)
```

Text file being read in (gaelic_flashcard_mode.txt):

```
I=mé=(pron) (emphatic)
I=mise=(n/a)
you=tú=(pron) (subject)
you=tusa=(emphatic)
y'all=sibh=(plural)
y'all=sibhse=(emphatic)
he=sé=(pron)
he=é=(n/a)
he=seisean=(emphatic)
he=eisean=(n/a)
she=sí=(pron)
she=í=(n/a)
she=sise=(emphatic)
she=ise=(emphatic)
him=é=(pron)
him=eisean=(emphatic)
her=í=(pron)
her=ise=(emphatic)
her=a=(adj)
```

Comment: Aside: it looks to me like `flashcards` will only wind up with the `trans` and `PoS` corresponding to the last `key` read for each of the `key`s.  I.e. you'll only have `'her': ['a', '(adj)']`, not `['ise', '(emphatic)']` or anything.

Comment: Works fine for me. I don't get any error. What python version are you using on what platform?

Comment: Did you copy-paste this code from somewhere else? Another text editor, perhaps? In that case, it's possible that the `:` is not an ascii `:`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Python 3.X?  Your print statements seem to indicate so.

Use the `encoding` parameter of `open` to specify the encoding of the source file.

Also, since you have multiple "keys" a dictionary can't hold the various versions of `him`, `her`, etc., so you probably want a list instead:

```
def Gaelic():
    with open('gaelic_flashcard_mode.txt','r',encoding='utf8') as f:
        return [tuple(line.rstrip().split('=')) for line in f]

print(Gaelic())
```

Output:

```
[('I', 'mé', '(pron) (emphatic)'), ('I', 'mise', '(n/a)'), ('you', 'tú', '(pron) (subject)'), ('you', 'tusa', '(emphatic)'), ("y'all", 'sibh', '(plural)'), ("y'all", 'sibhse', '(emphatic)'), ('he', 'sé', '(pron)'), ('he', 'é', '(n/a)'), ('he', 'seisean', '(emphatic)'), ('he', 'eisean', '(n/a)'), ('she', 'sí', '(pron)'), ('she', 'í', '(n/a)'), ('she', 'sise', '(emphatic)'), ('she', 'ise', '(emphatic)'), ('him', 'é', '(pron)'), ('him', 'eisean', '(emphatic)'), ('her', 'í', '(pron)'), ('her', 'ise', '(emphatic)'), ('her', 'a', '(adj)')]
```

Comment: Your encoding method worked for me in Idle, but when I run it from terminal it says, "TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function logout"

Comment: Were you running the same version of Python?  The above requires Python 3.X.  Python 2.X doesn't have an encoding parameter for built-in `open`.

Comment: Yes, I've been running Python 3.X for all of this.

Comment: My only guess is that ‘open‘ has been accidentally redefined, since ‘encoding‘ *is* a valid keyword for that function.  Publish an standalone script demoing the problem with traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using `open()` to open a non-ASCII text file. Use [`codecs.open()`](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) instead, passing it the appropriate encoding. And [read this](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/).

Comment: It looks like Python 3...in which case, `open` does work (it takes an optional `encoding` parameter)